# Get Error on window.open() from jQuery Ajax success callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I've got a `POST` Ajax request which is calling a function on my web server backend (`Grails 2.2.0`). The web server returns a `JSON` object which contains a URL to another web page. On the success callback of the Ajax request, I try to redirect the user to another page like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'external/location',
  data: {account: 'myAccount'},
  success: function(data) {
    if(typeof data.redirect !== 'undefined') {
      var win = window.open(data.redirect, '_blank'); // <-- here I open another window/tab
      win.focus();
    }
  }
});
```

this obviously works, but however I receive the following error message in the developer console of my `Chrome` web browser:

```
Blocked a frame with origin "http://the.redirected.page" from accessing a frame with origin "http://my.page". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

I guess a `JSONP` is not the right weapon to destroy the issue, as I'm not querying a *foreign* server, but I'm redirecting to another server within the Ajax `success:` callback?

NOTE: I don't use plain Javascript, but `Ember.JS 1.0.0-rc3` along with `jQuery 1.9.1`.

Comment: It seems that is saying that both URLs must be in the same domain to do that. It's caused by `Same origin policy`: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: @DaGLiMiOuX thanks for your answer! I'm totally aware of this issue, that's why I brought in the `JSONP` keyword. Sorry that I didn't mentioned it in my initial post.